# SQL: select 3 values and count how many times they are different

Tags: sql, select, subquery

Say that you need to query some data and that there are three fields like the following (this is part of a larger query):
`Field1`, `Field2`, `Field3`.

So you select them like this:

```
SELECT Field1=MyTable.Field1, Field2=MyTable.Field2, Field3=MyTable.Field3
FROM MyTable
```

I need to compare these values and return the variable `Result` that is computed as follows:

- 0 if they are all the same
- 1/2 if two are the same and one is different
- 1 if they are all different.

How should I restructure my query? I think I need a subquery but I am not sure how to structure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
select (case when field1 = field2 and field1 = field3 then 0
             when field1 in (field2, field3) or field2 = field3 then 0.5
             else 1
        end) as result
```

Comment: If I do it like this, the returned values wouldn't be associated with any variable name. Where should the variable name `Result` go?

Comment: imply add `as result`

Comment: Check my edits. These variables are assigned a different name when selected. Will this not create confusion by having too many `=` signs in the query?

Comment: @Zizzipupp . . . Actually, the names you are assigning are the same as the columns would be given anyway.  But yes, you should use the qualified column names for the expressions in the `case`.